# what is the javascript mechanism/rules that allow `p.foo = o.foo` to return a reference to the function `foo`?

Tags: javascript, function, this, indirection

I'm currently studying javascript by following the book "you dont know js" series.

In the "this & object prototype" section, when discussing "indirect references to functions", the author states

> ```
> function foo() {
>   console.log( this.a );
> }
>
> var a = 2;
> var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
> var p = { a: 4 };
>
> o.foo(); // 3
> (p.foo = o.foo)(); // 2
> ```
>
> The result value of the assignment expression p.foo = o.foo is a
>   reference to just the underlying function object. As such, the
>   effective call-site is just foo(), not p.foo() or o.foo() as you might
>   expect. Per the rules above, the default binding rule applies.

So apparently, `(p.foo = o.foo)` return a reference to the function `foo`. But  what is the mechanism/rules that allow  `(p.foo = o.foo)` return a reference to the function `foo`? In other words, why a simple assignment return a reference to `foo` function?

Comment: Because an assignment evaluates to the *value* of the right hand side. And not to a property reference, as `o.foo` in the method call `o.foo()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to understand something like this, I find it helpful to break it down step by step.

1. `o.foo` looks at the `o` object and finds a property named `foo`. It returns a reference that property, whatever it might be. In this case, the `o.foo` property is a reference to the function `foo`.
2. `p.foo = o.foo` takes the result from above (a reference to the function `foo`), creates a property in the `p` object which is also named `foo`. So now `p.foo` is also a reference to the `foo` function, exactly the same thing as `o.foo`.
3. That expression is wrapped in parentheses, so now you have whatever was on the left side of the `=` sign, or `p.foo`, which is (as a reminder) still a reference to the `foo` function.
4. Now we find the `()` at the end. This calls whatever function we have on hand at this moment. That is the `foo` function. Note in particular that we are *not* calling `p.foo()`. That would be a method call to the function that `p.foo` is a reference to, so inside that function, `this` would be set to `p`. But we're not doing that. We're just calling whatever function was returned by `( p.foo = o.foo )`. As before, this is the same `foo` function, but we've now lost any connection it may have ever had to the `o` object or the `p` object.
5. So, when we make that call at the end, we are merely calling the `foo` function without setting `this` to any particular object. Because of that, when we make the call, `this` is set to `undefined`.
6. But we're not running in `strict` mode, so JavaScript "helpfully" doesn't want to give us an undefined `this`, so it sets `this` to the `window` object in a browser or the `global` object in Node.
7. Previously we did `var a = 2;`. So the `window` or `global` object actually now has a property named `a`, and the value of that property is `2`.
8. So now when we do the `console.log(this.a)`, we pick up the `a` property from the `window` or `global` object. That value is `2`.

What if all this code was not running at the global level, but instead it was inside a function? What would happen then?

```js
function test() {
  function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
  }
  
  var a = 2;
  var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
  var p = { a: 4 };

  o.foo(); // 3
  (p.foo = o.foo)(); // was 2, but now is undefined
}

test();
```

Now when we call `console.log( this.a );` inside `foo`, `this` still refers to the `window` or `global` object. But when we set `var a = 2;`, we aren't setting a global property any more. We're just creating a local variable. `window.a` or `global.a` is `undefined` (unless some other code previously set it).

Strict mode avoids some this weirdness. If we put a `'use strict';` at the top of the code, it will compile in strict mode. And now when we make that last function call at the end, where we're calling the `foo` function (again not as a method!), `this` is now set to `undefined` instead of `window` or `global`. Therefore, when we try to call `console.log(this.a)`, the code fails because `this` is the same as `undefined`, and `undefined` does not (and couldn't) have an `a` property.

Let's try it:

```js
'use strict';

function foo() {
  console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;
var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
var p = { a: 4 };

o.foo(); // 3
(p.foo = o.foo)(); // was 2 in the original, but now throws an exception
```

The bottom line, at least for this particular example: always use strict mode! It is your friend.

Comment: I was just about to post an incomplete answer with basically step 8 from yours missing. Thanks for making sense of the bit I couldn't quite work out. I knew `this` was the `window` but didn't know why. Upvoted :-)

Comment: Actually, in step 5, `this` is specifically passed as `undefined`. Step 8 is irrelevant - it has nothing to do with the kind of call. It's step 6 where the sloppy mode function casts the `this` value to an object, and replaces `null` or `undefined` with the global object.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I get for doing a "stream of consciousness" overview. :-) I updated it with your corrections, hopefully got it closer this time! (And for anyone reading the comments, I took out step 8, so 9 is the new 8...)

Comment: @FredGandt thanks for your answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it correct to assume that '(p.foo = o.foo)();` is the same as 'var q = (p.foo = o.foo)' and then 'q()'? I tried the code in chrome console and they seem to be behaving as I expected.

Comment: @Bergi do you mind if I ask, how did you got to know such intrinsic details of how javascript work? A bit of wisdom from you would help beginners like me to go a long way. :)

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Yes, those are the same. In both cases you've gotten a reference to the `foo` function and then called it directly as a function, not as a method.

Comment: @MichaelGeary now it makes perfect sense! thanks again for helping out!

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Years of StackOverflow experience :-)

Comment: @CaptainAmerica - As Michael has explained, the result of the assignment is whatever the value being assigned is, so yes `q = (foo = bar)` will result in `q` having the value of `foo` and `bar`. It equates to `q = foo = bar`.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica - Just my opinion, but if the book your reading doesn't explain the examples it gives, you might want to consider using it as firelighters instead of reading it. Over the years, I've encountered a lot of "experts" who love to _show off_, but rarely say anything helpful. Consider the real world practicality of that last line in your excerpt code; would you ever really want to do that?

Comment: @FredGandt yeah, I definitely agree with parts of your comment. The author tends to go into the nooks and crannies when explaining things, and I agree that the last line of code are unlikely to have much real world implications, but I guess it doesn't hurt to know the details of javascript, just in case it is needed (however unlikely) down the track.

Comment: I'll rephrase: would it have not been simpler to understand if the last line(s) was `var q = o.foo; q(); // 2`? This imparts that `o.foo` returns `foo()` and turns `q` into a proxy, without the baffling parenthesized assignment call. If the code is minified production code, it can be as alien as you like as long as it works, but an educator should make every effort to provide simple, clear walkthroughs. The book should also explain the reason for the return of `2` immediately after showing alien code that returns it. Anyhoo; was interesting :-)

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `=` is an expression in JavaScript that produces (returns) the assigned value. Because it is an expression it can be used anywhere an expression is allowed, such as inside parenthesis.

For example:

```
let test = (a = b = c = { name: 'test' })
```

The code above would first evaluate the expression in the parenthesis and point the variables `c`, `b`, and `a` to the test object (in that order), then it would  point `test` to the produced value from this expression. After that line is executed, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `test` will all point to the same object.

Similarly,

```
(p.foo = o.foo)
```

Would produce `o.foo` back (technically it would produce whatever `o.foo` is pointing to, which is the function `foo`).

As far as

```
(p.foo = o.foo)()
```

By adding the additional `()` after the parenths, we are telling the engine that we want to invoke whatever the expression `(p.foo = o.foo)` ends up producing. Thus we end up invoking the function `foo`. [Similar patterns is used in IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

A helpful rewrite would be to think of the line above as doing this:

```
let produced = (p.foo = o.foo)
produced()
```

[Further reading about statements vs expressions](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html).

Comment: This does not explain why `(p.foo = o.foo)()` `log`s `2`

Comment: @FredGandt but that wasn't the question? Q: "But what is the mechanism/rules that allow  (p.foo = o.foo) return a reference to the function foo?"

Comment: Fair point (on review); perhaps it should have been though ;-)

Comment: -1 for the first two paragraphs that are complete nonsense. One doesn't "declare statements", there are no "statement expressions", and assignments don't evaluate to the left-most variable.

Comment: …one cannot wrap statements in parenthesis, and you can try out that `p.foo` is not read back by making it a getter/setter property.

Comment: If you introduce a `temp` variable for the righthandside value in your final snippet, it might almost be correct

Comment: @nem035 thanks for all the links in the answer! reading them right now :)

Comment: @CaptainAmerica no problem mate, glad to help. Happy JavaScripting :)